# Chosen search results not working in Hebrew

Tags: jquery-chosen, hebrew

**SOLVED SEE UPDATE BELOW**

I have set up a the chosen library to work with my system. When I work with option in English everything is perfect. However when I work with option in Hebrew a problem appears:

When I use the quick search option to type in the option, Chosen recognizes the option according to the search and i am able to select it. BUT the display of the option (before it is selected) is not working well. It only shows the last character of the option, instead of the whole word.

I looked into the elements and the rest of the word is not there in the data of the html element, so it is not a matter of hidden content.

I am using the RTL option. Somewhere along the script it messes up the fetching of the Hebrew option and only fetches the last character I guess.

Does anyone have a clue on how to approach this issue?

I didn't attach any code because it's a rather general issue and everything works perfect aside for that. Also the library itself is completely external to my code.

> **UPDATE**
>
> Changed from chosen version 1.7 to chosen 1.8.2 and now it works great.